# Compare list of numbers to see if they match in Android

Tags: android, match

I have a list of numbers, in that list I want to check if any of the numbers match, and if so return 'true'.  Essentially, what I want to check is if the numbers match, then do not save.  I've gotten a seemingly very inefficient method to check. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
if (mFav1Compare == mNumber1Compare || mFav1Compare == mNumber2Compare || mFav1Compare == mNumber3Compare || mFav1Compare == mNumber4Compare || mFav1Compare == mNumber5Compare) {
        return true;
    }

    if (mFav2Compare == mNumber1Compare || mFav2Compare == mNumber2Compare || mFav2Compare == mNumber3Compare || mFav2Compare == mNumber4Compare || mFav2Compare == mNumber5Compare) {
        return true;
    }

    if (mFav3Compare == mNumber1Compare || mFav3Compare == mNumber2Compare || mFav3Compare == mNumber3Compare || mFav3Compare == mNumber4Compare || mFav3Compare == mNumber5Compare) {
        return true;
    }

    if (mFav4Compare == mNumber1Compare || mFav4Compare == mNumber2Compare || mFav4Compare == mNumber3Compare || mFav4Compare == mNumber4Compare || mFav4Compare == mNumber5Compare) {
        return true;
    }

    if (mFav5Compare == mNumber1Compare || mFav5Compare == mNumber2Compare || mFav5Compare == mNumber3Compare || mFav5Compare == mNumber4Compare || mFav5Compare == mNumber5Compare) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: yup, just posted, sorry about that.

Comment: Look up what a HashSet is.  Heck, or even how to loop over an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two lists and you want to know if the second list contains at least one element of the first list you could try

```
public <T> boolean listMatches(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    for (T element : list1) {
        if (list2.contains(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you thought this?

```
ArrayList<Integer>listNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

listNumbers.add(99);
listNumbers.add(99);
listNumbers.add(11);
listNumbers.add(10);
for(int i = 0; i < listNumbers.size(); i++){
    if(!listCheck(listNumbers.get(i))){
      //save something
    }

}
```

and this method

```
private boolean listCheck(int number){

  for(int i = 0; i < listNumbers.size(); i++){
     if(number == listNumbers.get(i)){
        return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```